# Lazy propagation of segment tree can't be updated in a condition

Tags: algorithm, segment-tree

For example, here is a array [88, 23, 58, 10, 47, 66] and I want to query the min value in a range.

If I add 100 to the range [1,4] with lazy propagation, the lazy tag will be tagged to the segment of range [1,4].

However, if I query the range [0,5], the result will be still 10 because it doesn't reach the segment [1,4].

the code example in Javascript:

```
class SegmentTree {

    constructor(arr){
        this.arr = arr;
        this.tree = new Array(4 * arr.length);
        this.tag = new Array(4 * arr.length).fill(0);
        this.buildTree(0, 0, arr.length - 1);
    }

    buildTree(vertex, start, end){
        // the end node
        if(start === end){
            this.tree[vertex] = this.arr[start];
            return;
        }

        const mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
        const left = 2 * vertex + 1;
        const right = 2 * vertex + 2;

        this.buildTree(left, start, mid);
        this.buildTree(right, mid + 1, end);

        this.tree[vertex] = Math.min(this.tree[left], this.tree[right]);
    }

    queryRange(vertex, start, end, rangeStart, rangeEnd){

        if(rangeStart === start && rangeEnd === end){
            return this.tree[vertex] + this.tag[vertex];
        }

        this.push(vertex);
        const mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
        const left = 2 * vertex + 1;
        const right = 2 * vertex + 2;

        if(rangeStart > mid){
            return this.queryRange(right, mid + 1, end, rangeStart, rangeEnd);
        } else if(rangeEnd <= mid){
            return this.queryRange(left, start, mid , rangeStart, rangeEnd);
        } else {
            return Math.min(this.queryRange(left, start, mid, rangeStart, mid), this.queryRange(right, mid + 1, end, mid + 1, rangeEnd));
        }
    }

    update(vertex, start, end, pos, value){
        if(start === end){
            this.tree[vertex] = value;
            this.arr[pos] = value;
            return;
        }

        const mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
        const left = 2 * vertex + 1;
        const right = 2 * vertex + 2;

        if(pos >= start && pos <= mid){
            this.update(left, start, mid, pos, value);
        } else {
            this.update(left, mid + 1, end, pos, value);
        }

        this.tree[vertex] = Math.min(this.tree[left], this.tree[right]);
    }

    updateRange(vertex, start, end, rangeStart, rangeEnd, value){
        
        if(rangeStart <= start && rangeEnd >= end){
            this.tag[vertex] += value;
            return;
        }

        const mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
        const left = 2 * vertex + 1;
        const right = 2 * vertex + 2;

        if(rangeStart > mid){
            this.updateRange(right, mid + 1, end, rangeStart, rangeEnd, value);
        } else if(rangeEnd <= mid){
            this.updateRange(left, start, mid , rangeStart, rangeEnd, value);
        } else {
            this.updateRange(right, mid + 1, end, rangeStart, rangeEnd, value);
            this.updateRange(left, start, mid , rangeStart, rangeEnd, value);
        }
    }

    push(vertex){       
        const left = 2 * vertex + 1;
        const right = 2 * vertex + 2;
        this.tag[left] += this.tag[vertex];
        this.tag[right] += this.tag[vertex];
        this.tree[vertex] += this.tag[vertex];
        this.tag[vertex] = 0;
    }


}

const sum = [88, 23, 58, 10, 47, 66];
const tree = new SegmentTree(sum);
console.log(`before update: ${tree.queryRange(0, 0, sum.length - 1, 0, 5)}`);
tree.updateRange(0, 0, sum.length - 1, 1, 4, 100);
console.log(`after update: ${tree.queryRange(0, 0, sum.length - 1, 0, 5)}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved the problem. It is because I hasn't merged up the two child nodes after updated range.

The updated code:

```
class SegmentTree {

    constructor(arr){
        this.arr = arr;
        this.tree = new Array(4 * arr.length);
        this.tag = new Array(4 * arr.length).fill(0);
        this.buildTree(0, 0, arr.length - 1);
    }

    buildTree(vertex, start, end){
        // the end node
        if(start === end){
            this.tree[vertex] = this.arr[start];
            return;
        }

        const mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
        const left = 2 * vertex + 1;
        const right = 2 * vertex + 2;

        this.buildTree(left, start, mid);
        this.buildTree(right, mid + 1, end);

        this.tree[vertex] = Math.min(this.tree[left], this.tree[right]);
    }

    queryRange(vertex, start, end, rangeStart, rangeEnd){

        if(rangeStart === start && rangeEnd === end){
            return this.tree[vertex] + this.tag[vertex];
        }

        this.push(vertex);
        const mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
        const left = 2 * vertex + 1;
        const right = 2 * vertex + 2;

        if(rangeStart > mid){
            return this.queryRange(right, mid + 1, end, rangeStart, rangeEnd);
        } else if(rangeEnd <= mid){
            return this.queryRange(left, start, mid , rangeStart, rangeEnd);
        } else {
            return Math.min(this.queryRange(left, start, mid, rangeStart, mid), this.queryRange(right, mid + 1, end, mid + 1, rangeEnd));
        }
    }

    update(vertex, start, end, pos, value){
        if(start === end){
            this.tree[vertex] = value;
            this.arr[pos] = value;
            return;
        }

        const mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
        const left = 2 * vertex + 1;
        const right = 2 * vertex + 2;

        if(pos >= start && pos <= mid){
            this.update(left, start, mid, pos, value);
        } else {
            this.update(left, mid + 1, end, pos, value);
        }

        this.tree[vertex] = Math.min(this.tree[left], this.tree[right]);
    }

    updateRange(vertex, start, end, rangeStart, rangeEnd, value){
        
        if(rangeStart <= start && rangeEnd >= end){
            this.tag[vertex] += value;
            this.tree[vertex] += value;
            return;
        }

        const mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
        const left = 2 * vertex + 1;
        const right = 2 * vertex + 2;

        if(rangeStart > mid){
            this.updateRange(right, mid + 1, end, rangeStart, rangeEnd, value);
        } else if(rangeEnd <= mid){
            this.updateRange(left, start, mid , rangeStart, rangeEnd, value);
        } else {
            this.updateRange(right, mid + 1, end, rangeStart, rangeEnd, value);
            this.updateRange(left, start, mid , rangeStart, rangeEnd, value);
        }
        this.tree[vertex] = Math.min(this.tree[left], this.tree[right]);
    }

    push(vertex){       
        const left = 2 * vertex + 1;
        const right = 2 * vertex + 2;
        this.tag[left] += this.tag[vertex];
        this.tag[right] += this.tag[vertex];
        this.tag[vertex] = 0;
    }


}

const sum = [88, 23, 58, 10, 47, 66];
const tree = new SegmentTree(sum);
console.log(`before update: ${tree.queryRange(0, 0, sum.length - 1, 0, 5)}`);
tree.updateRange(0, 0, sum.length - 1, 1, 4, 100);
console.log(`after update: ${tree.queryRange(0, 0, sum.length - 1, 0, 5)}`);
```